# insert object literals pushed into array in an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning!
I generate object literals from form values and I store them in an array as follows

```js
var persons  = {};// I want all the objects in the array to be inserted here so that I can stringify it and send via Ajax
var array = [];// where I store the object literals
var courses = {};
course['name'] = $('#course').val();
array.push(courses);
var students = {};
students['first'] = $('#first_name').val();
students['last'] = $('#last_name').val();
students['age'] = $('age').val();
array.push(courses);
// I tried this after the help I got this morning but it does not create multiple objects. When there are many successive values, the data sent is empty 
var persons = {
    courses: {
        name: $('#course').val(),
    },
    students: {
        name: $('#first_name').val(),
        last: $('#last_name').val(),
        age: $('#age').val(),
    },
};
```

Please does anybody know how I can create several students and have them in the same object with the course name?

Comment: When you only want to use `stringify`, why not just `JSON.stringify({[]})`?

Comment: First of all, "course['name'] = $('#course').val();" will be "courses['name'] = $('#course').val();"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter your code as follows

```
 courses = {
        name: $('#course').val(),
        students: []
 };
```

to add a student you do:

```
courses.students.push({
        name: $('#first_name').val(),
        last: $('#last_name').val(),
        age: $('#age').val(),
    })
```

Comment: thank you very much it works great. Please do you have any idea if I still need to decode it on server side before storing the values?

Comment: depends  on your database, how you send them,etcetera

Comment: I sent the data via ajax to the processing script. I have to get the data unpack the data  and store it in two tables courses and students.

Comment: you should have a array of students when you do $_GET['students']